# Finding optimal blend of items to meet certain criteria

Tags: optimization

Math beginner here. Say I have the following items

`Marsbar: sugar 100/lb, salt 5/lb, price $4/lb, inventory: 40lb`

`Twix:    sugar 100/lb, salt 9/lb, price $7/lb, inventory:  9lb`

`Bounty:  sugar 105/lb, salt 4/lb, price $3/lb, inventory: 10lb`

and I need to make a `3 lb` blend of these items to the lowest price, where the minimum criteria for the blend is:

`sugar: 101/lb, salt: 6/lb`

Does anyone know how to solve this or can maybe give me a hint, and potentially with more properties than sugar and salt?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I believe it is $3$lb, not $31$, so $x+y+z=3$. Also, the last two equations are inequalities as $101$ and $6$ per pound are minimum values.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Sorry if that is unclear, it is supposed to say 3 lb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Words to equations:
$$\begin{cases}100m+100t+105b\geq 101\times 3\\5m+9t+4b\geq 6\times 3\\m+t+b=3\end{cases}$$
where $m$ is the pounds of Marsbars, $t$ for Twix, and $b$ for Bounty. We want to minimize $P=4m+7t+3b$, where $P$ is the total price. The above system yields $b\geq\frac{3}{5}$ and $t\geq\frac{9}{10}$ and $m\geq\frac{3}{2}$ by simple rearranging and substitution. Hence, the minimum solution occurs at $(m,t,b)=\left(\frac{3}{2},\frac{9}{10},\frac{3}{5}\right)$ with a price of $\$14.10$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that! Now that I see your equation I think I know how to do the rearranging and substitutions, but how do I minimize 4m + 7t + 3b in that process to get your result?

Comment: The constraints come from the system, as if you increase any one of the quantities you add more cost.

Comment: Ah yes. But what I dont think I understand is, when you have a combination of the candybars' properties and the minimum criteria for the blend, where many different blends would meet the minimum criteria (which to my understandig solving the first three line equation in your answer will show?), then how do i go from there to knowing which of the many solutions is the cheapest?

Comment: Effectively, we are trying to minimize $P$ with the constraints $$\begin{cases}5b\geq 3\\4t-b\geq 3\end{cases}$$by using $m=3-t-b$. Notice that the only corner point of the above system in the $bt$-plane is at $(b,t)=\left(\frac{3}{5},\frac{9}{10}\right)$. So this is where the minimum of $P$ occurs.